# iOS Help: loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have a class called TaskListViewController and I am going to ShowTaskViewController. In the beginning in ShowTaskViewController I didn't have a view object I only Had a TableView object where I was dynamically loading data from a database and it worked fine.

Now I deleted the TableView object in ShowTaskViewController class and I dragged and dropped a View object in the .xib file and also dragged and dropped a TableView object on top of it because I want to have some additional buttons in that class, but now its showing me this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ShowTaskViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Also this is the code I used to go to the ShowTaskViewController class before when it worked fine, now please help me to make the changes so the TableView object loads data properly.

```
-(IBAction)showAllTasks:(id)sender
{
    ShowTaskViewController *showTaskViewController = [[ShowTaskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowTaskViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:showTaskViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first declare outlet for your new tableView(Ctrl + Drag from xib to interface file)
and later do something like this:

```
self.view=myTableView;
```

Comment: I just tried doing that, but its still showing the same error. Am I doing anything else wrong? Please help!

Comment: @Shahnawaz It must work, if this is your first view controller, you have to check AppDelegate too, because you will need to rename the xib file mentioned there too

Comment: btw, you have deleted the xib file and still trying to push it, rename your new added xib with ShowTaskViewController

Comment: Oh no this is my fifth view controller class, 1st I made a class that is subclass of UITableViewController and then it only had the UITableView in the .xib file. Then I changed it to a subclass of UIViewController and implements interfaces: <UITableViewDataSourceDelegate, UITableViewDelegate> (I forgot the exact names but its of this region).

Answer (score 9):

This is because in you xib your haven't set your view outlet.

Open you xib file select `File Owner` right click it and map your view outlet to your UIView in the xib.

For more detail plz check following links:

[Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)

[Error in Xcode "the view outlet was not set.'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327239/error-in-xcode-the-view-outlet-was-not-set)

Hope this helps :)